# Update to "FreeBSD 8.1-RELEASE #1"

Tags: freebsd, update

I've updated my FreeBSD system with "freebsd-update" but "uname -a" still sais it runs the ""FreeBSD 8.1-RELEASE #0" kernel.

How do I get #1? Its important because I need ZFS v15.

Comment: What was you exact command? `freebsd-update fetch` and `freebsd-update install`? And did you `reboot` ?

Comment: Yes, and of course I rebooted.

Comment: I think what you want is -p1 or -p2, not #1: FreeBSD 8.1-RELEASE-p2

Comment: Kernel and RELEASE are not synchronized. I'm on p2: "No updates needed to update system to 8.1-RELEASE-p2"

Comment: You need user and group space accounting? ZFSv14 was included with 8.1-RELEASE.

Comment: I need to import a v15 zpool, therefore I need a v15 kernel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, that the install image of my root server provider was patched with a ZFS v15 patch, but the rescue system is not.

Answer (score 0):

Your upgrade worked just fine. The #0 will not change after an update but the -p**X** will change.

If you want to upgrade your ZFS version don't forget to run `zpool upgrade` after freebsd-update.

Please note that currently v14 is included in the 8.1-RELEASE version.

Good luck.

EDIT: Sorry, I didn't read your last comment. Please check out this link and switch to **CURRENT** branch: http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/current-stable.html